# How can I have context for more than one activity using a database connection?

Tags: android

I have a main activity that has a opens a view form when the floating action button is clicked.

I have a Database Connection class to create the database and an entry controller class to define the sql methods.

I make 2 calls to the database in the `onclicklistener` that I have defined as part of the view form. They add and return information to the database back to my `MainActivity`.

The problem is that I have added another activity to create pie charts and when I make a call to the database using the method `(todayPie())` I have defined in my entry controller I am getting a `null pointer exception` on

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase()
```

I assume I don't have `context` for the new activity to make the database call and *I am unsure of how to fix it?*

**My EntryController Class:**

```
public class EntryController extends DatabaseConnection {

    public EntryController(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public boolean create(Entry entry) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    //adds new entry to the database
        values.put("moodName", entry.moodName);
        values.put("location", entry.location);
        values.put("moodRating", entry.moodRating);

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        boolean createSuccessful = db.insert("moodEntry", null, values) > 0;
        db.close();

        return createSuccessful;
    }

    //counts records in the database
    public int count() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM moodEntry";
        int recordCount = db.rawQuery(sql, null).getCount();
        db.close();

        return recordCount;
    }

    // reads records from the database
    public List<Entry> read() {
        List<Entry> entryList = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM moodEntry ORDER BY timeStamp DESC";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String moodName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("moodName"));
                String location = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("location"));
                String timeStamp = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("timeStamp"));
                int moodRating = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("moodRating")));
                Entry entry = new Entry();
                entry.moodName = moodName;
                entry.location = location;
                entry.timeStamp = timeStamp;
                entry.moodRating = moodRating;

                entryList.add(entry);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return entryList;
    }

    //reads moodRatings from the database as a total count for each mood type for date == today
    public int[] todayPie() {
        int[] today_data = new int[]{2, 2, 2, 2, 2};
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

       for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        String sql = "select count(moodRating) from moodEntry where moodRating = " + i + 1 + " and date('now');";
           Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
           cursor.moveToFirst();
          today_data[i] = cursor.getInt(0);
           cursor.close();
       }
       db.close();
        return today_data;
    }
}
```

My error log:

```
                                                                             --------- beginning of crash
```

04-18 12:07:47.896 4882-4882/com.package.userc.moodtrackeruni E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.package.userc.moodtrackeruni, PID: 4882
                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.package.userc.moodtrackeruni/com.package.userc.moodtrackeruni.Pie2Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2567)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference
                                                                                     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:289)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
                                                                                     at com.package.userc.moodtrackeruni.EntryController.todayPie(EntryController.java:80)
                                                                                     at com.package.userc.moodtrackeruni.Pie2Activity.(Pie2Activity.java:21)
                                                                                     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2557)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Comment: in your constructor for controller class, initialize context and than use that context.

Comment: Post your error log.

Comment: I think you are making a mistake. Every Activity knows its context.

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution

1. First create instance :

   ```
       public class YourApplication extends Application {

       private static YourApplication mInstance;
       private static String TAG = YourApplication.class.getName();

       public static synchronized YourApplication getInstance() {
           return mInstance;
       }

       @Override
       public void onCreate() {
           super.onCreate();
           mInstance = this;

       }
   }
   ```
2. In your DBHandler class write down like this for instance :

   ```
       public class HM_DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements HM_DBhelper {
       public static final String DB_NAME = "DevicesList.db";
       public static int DB_VERSION = 2;
       private static HM_DBHandler dbInstance;

       public HM_DBHandler(Context context) {
           super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
       }

       public static HM_DBHandler getInstance() {
           return dbInstance == null ? dbInstance = new HM_DBHandler(YourApplication.getInstance()) : dbInstance;
       }

       @Override

       public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
           // create table
       }

       @Override
       public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
       // drop table if exsts
          // db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TableNames.DEVICE_LIST_TABLE);
         //  onCreate(db);
       }
   ```

// For inserting

```
    public long insertDevicesListValues(String name, String address, String status) {

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(Columns.DeviceListItems.DEVICE_NAME, name);
        cv.put(Columns.DeviceListItems.DEVICE_ADDRESS, address);
        cv.put(Columns.DeviceListItems.DEVICE_STATUS, status);
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        long id = db.insert(TableNames.DEVICE_LIST_TABLE, null, cv);
        db.close();
        return id;
    }
```

// For update

```
    public boolean updateStatus(String address, String status) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(Columns.DeviceListItems.DEVICE_STATUS, status);
        final boolean b = db.update(TableNames.DEVICE_LIST_TABLE, args, Columns.DeviceListItems.DEVICE_ADDRESS + "='" + address + "'", null) > 0;
        return b;
    }
```

// For delete

```
    public boolean deleteRecord(String address, String status) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(TableNames.DEVICE_LIST_TABLE, Columns.DeviceListItems.DEVICE_ADDRESS + "='" + address + "'", null) > 0;
    }
    }
```

3. After that in your just call like this you will get instance of db.

   ```
        HM_DBHandler.getInstance() // Here you can do anything like HM_DBHandler.getInstance(). insert(...)
   ```